# Don't want to exit program when user click on Close button in titlebar of C# app

Tags: c#, titlebar

Working on development of C# application.

I want to keep Close button on top right in title bar, but if end users click on it, all I want is that he gets info window that he can not close application until some other proper button.

Is it possible to achieve?

Tnx in adv!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the `FormClosing` event event handler like this

```
private void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    //there can be other reasons for form close make sure X button is clicked
    // if close button clicked
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add an event handler to the `OnClosing` event of the form. The event argument contains an element `Cancel`. Set it to `true` and it won't close.

Essentially something like this:

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = !stuffdone;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to display a message box showing the reason why application is not shutdown...

Comment: Well, that's part of the other code to be added already, I guess.

Comment: tnx, it works, but now i have problem that if user clicks on button that is planned to be used for closing of application, it always call Form1_Closing action... can i somehow avoid that?

Comment: see my answer for that. You need to add check if it is the cross button or not

Comment: You'd have to set `stuffdone` once your button is pushed (or whatever you call that variable). Also Haris' "reason" checking won't hurt, especially if you don't want to keep Windows from shutting down etc.